# CalDigit TS3 Plus causing WiFi packet loss

Tags: networking, macbook, caldigit

I've got a Macbook Pro connected to a CalDigit TS3 plus. The Macbook has an internet connection over WiFi, and a local non-internet connection via ethernet on the CalDigit. What I've noticed is that the WiFi connection experiences extreme packet loss in waves when the ethernet port is connected. When the ethernet cable is unplugged, the packet loss improves, but is still present. When the CalDigit is disconnected, the packet loss disappears entirely.

Is this a known issue with the CalDigit TS3 Plus? Could it be an issue with my specific one? Is there something else entirely that I'm missing?

I've reached out to CalDigit support, and I'm waiting to hear back from them as well.

Comment: It's a known issue of interference, also with HDMI ports, in some cheap laptops. Quite surprising with a Macbook and a fancy dock.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I think you're right - I disconnected the HDMI cable, and the interference has disappeared. Connection was via a CalDigit USB Type-C to HDMI cable.

Comment: @ChanganAuto If you make your comment an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: I think it would be better if you did it with your own solution, if we can call it that. I merely informed, in comments, about something I was aware of but not even related with docks, hence my (double, we should say) surprise. I've read a few reports about, again, cheap laptops where using an USB3.0 port located close to the HDMI port caused interference with the peripherals and/or WiFi itself. The common factor seemed to be the presence of USB3.x cables or traces without enough shielding placed close to other buses.